# How to select a column from a pandas dataframe to be plotted without addressing its name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I need to plot data from a column, and I want to do it without using its name.

The problem is, I want to have user input to make the the analysis customised, and it means I'll always get a different name for the column, thus having to change the name manually for the plot. Any possible solutions to make it automatic?

[image: The original code:]

I tried

```py
stocks_ret.iloc[0,1].plot(figsize=(16,8), grid=True)
```

I also tried using `.iloc` but got

> AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'plot'

Comment: `.iloc` isn't going to solve your problem, and will probably only make it worse. With `.iloc` the user needs to not only know the column name, but it's position in your DataFrame. That's almost certainly worse than just knowing the column name. Just write your analysis function with an argument `col`, which is a string that the user specifies, and then you can plot whatever string they pass with `df[col].plot()` inside the function

Comment: you're trying to plot one value

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
stocks_ret.iloc[0,1].plot(figsize=(16,8), grid=True)
```

to

```
stocks_ret.iloc[:,1].plot(figsize=(16,8), grid=True)
```

#### explanation

`iloc` works by selecting row and column indices to extract from your dataframe, using the syntax `my_dataframe.iloc[row_range, column_range]`. For example, by writing `my_dataframe.iloc[0:2, 0:4]`, you're asking to extract the values *from the first to third row* and *from the first to fifth column* (remember, indices start at 0 in Python).

Similarly, by writing `my_dataframe.iloc[2, 3]`, you're asking what's the *specific value* inside `my_dataframe` at the third row, fourth column. This is what you've done in your code. Since it returns a single value, and not a pandas series/dataframe, it doesn't have a plot attribute, resulting in the error you see.

In order to select the whole column, you need to pass a range equivalent to the whole column's length, instead of a single index. The `:` notation can be used as a shorthand to do exactly that, so that `my_dataframe.iloc[:, 3]` returns the series of **all values** in the fourth column.